# Is ANZLIC Metadata supported using the new approach of ArcGIS 10.x?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, metadata, australia, new-zealand

I like the new approach to metadata at ArcGIS 10 because I fall into the camp that prefers minimal metadata for many purposes, but like to have the option to work with more comprehensive standards when they are appropriate.

My understanding is that the ANZLIC Metadata Profile 1.1 (based on ISO 19115) is very similar to the ISO 19139 Metadata Implementation Specification so can the ArcGIS 10 metadata style called ISO 19139 Metadata Implementation Specification simply be used or is the ArcGIS/ANZLIC community awaiting the release of an ANZLIC specific metadata style for ArcGIS 10 by Esri or a third party?

A reply to an [ArcGIS Discussion Forum thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/11229-metadata-and-anzlic-compliance) suggests that it might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an ANZLIC Compliant Metadata Editor for ArcGIS 10.2 available for download from [Esri Australia as its Metadata Editing Tool](https://esriaustralia.com.au/products-metadata-editing-tool).

Versions for ArcGIS 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3 and 10.5 can be downloaded from the same link.

Answer (score 2):

i'm having the same issue with ANZMET xmls and thought i'd pass on this info i found at link: http://www.linz.govt.nz/geospatial-office/about/projects-and-news/anzlic-metadata-profile/faq

If an ESRI software user has an Enterprise License Agreement (ELA) including ArcGIS Server products then the ANZLIC Metadata Profile functionality in the GeoPortal Server Extension for ArcGIS Server is included at no additional charge. For other ArcGIS Server users, charges apply, and for more information contact Eagle Technology (Parker Jones, psj@eagle.co.nz, 04 802 1036).

Answer (score 1):

As listed previously, ESRI Australia have been working on an ANZLIC editor for ArcGIS 10 and have recently made available their first version.  Contact them if you would like a copy.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Thank you for your informative answer! Would it be possible to add a link/reference to support your answer?

Comment: Thanks @damianw - heard that announcement from Craig Sandy at Esri APUC in Auckland a few weeks back and will contact him soon.  Have a feeling that it may be for 10.0 only but I am using 10.1 so a test install will soon tell.

Answer (score 0):

I have spoken with the people who wrote the former ANZLIC Metadata editor and as I understand it internally they have been working on a new editor. In my research for answering this question I have found that in the ArcGIS Desktop Gallery there is a Metadata Editor and XSLT available (written by Robyn Gallagher).

I have not tested this but based on my dealings with her this should be a good start point.

Comment: Thanks Christoper - I had not seen that but when I went looking for it and found it at http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/arcobjects-net-api/details?entryID=129152DD-1422-2418-345D-2714159B58B3 . I looked in its documenttion (*.rtf) and found: "It does NOT operate in the new Esri metadata paradigm, where you have a metadata style made up of a profile, an editor, a style sheet and a translator. So the editor is a temporary solution for people who have upgraded to ArcGIS 10, until Esri Australia organises a proper package embodying an ANZLIC metadata style."

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I will see what I can chase up my end as I do work for Esri Australia. Watch this space. CDB