# Metadata -auto build using python

Tags: python, mapinfo, open-source-gis, metadata

We have a large (10,000 plus) repository of spatial data (shp/gdb/tab vectors and ecw/tif rasters and also las, xyz and DEM data) where some have metadata records in xml using anzlic metadata editor. I want to check if each spatial dataset has an associated xml record and check the projections, spatial extent, source and size against the associated spatial file.

I have created a arcpy based script to extract this info from ESRI readable formats but am unsure on how to handle tab files and more importantly how to check it against the anzlic metaeditor based xml record.

So if we have citypoints.shp/.tab then we should have citypoints_metadata.shp/.tab.xml as the metadata record -this is separate from the citypoints.shp.xml that some software autocreate.

Another similar forum question is [Is ANZLIC Metadata supported using the new approach of ArcGIS 10.x?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6013/anzlic-metadata-in-arcgis-10) but it doesn't cover the requirement to check for the existence of a valid record and dealing with .tab (other non-esri) formats in an opensource/creative commons workspace as per my question ([How to read MapInfo .tab files in ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/how-to-read-mapinfo-tab-files-in-arcpy)). I also looked through the software mentioned in [Seeking Open Source ISO Metadata Editor?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16245/looking-for-a-metadata-editor) but none of them autogenerate the base metadata file or allow comparing of existing records against the source.

Comment: If anyone is interested I now have a qgis python based solution for this. Happy to share if anyone asks.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [NME project](https://github.com/spatialguru/NME)

With it, you can have all metadata supported by GDAL referenced in an XML (also an SQL output options) using the python script gdalogr_catalogue.py with a command like below

```
python gdalogr_catalogue.py -d /home/my_directory
```

After, it's up to you to adapt the retrieved XML from this utility to be able to compare it with anzlic metadata editor or to custom the original script to retrieve what you need exactly.

Answer (score 1):

have you considered using converting the non ESRI formats to ESRI formats? I was thinking if you script works well, why not use Gdaltranslate to convert the raster datasets and ogr2ogr to convert the vector datasets to ESRI formats. Ok, if you dont want to create new datasets maybe take a look at gdalinfo.exe and ogrinfo.exe like the names suggest they both produce meta data which could be helpful for you.

Comment: Don't want to create additional data -we have over 10k tab files to process.